# How to distinguish between 2 directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am looking at angular and i found directives very impressive feature of Angular js.

Here i am having one question --

Suppose i have 2 directives that are doing similar kind of work. for example i have 2 directives that add 1 subsection in an existing section and another directive is also doing same thing for other section. Now for these 2 directives i need to maintain 2 directives that will work on 2 different button clicks.

I need to know if i can have 1 directive that will work on the basis of button click and add subsection in a section whose button was clicked.

for reference please see below code.

To add two different buttons

```
mainApp.directive("addeducation", function(){
    return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<a href='' addedu>Click to add more sections</a>"
    }
 });

  mainApp.directive("addexperience", function(){
     return {
       restrict: "E",
        template: "<a href='' addexp>Click to add more sections</a>"
    }
  });
```

Two Directives to work on two different button press--

```
  mainApp.directive("addedu", function($compile){
      return function(scope, element, attrs){
         element.bind("click", function(){
         angular.element(document.getElementById('moreeducation')).append($compile("<edu-Info></edu-Info>")(scope));
    });
};
```

});

```
 mainApp.directive("addexp", function($compile){
     return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind("click", function(){
         angular.element(document.getElementById('moreexperience')).append($compile("      <experience></experience>")(scope));
       });
       };
    });
```

I want something like this :

```
 mainApp.directive("addedu", function($compile){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
    if(button1 clicked){
    then add section in experience section
    }
    else{
       add section in education section.
     }
  }
```

If somebody has already faced similar problem he/she can help. I need to implement this since i dont want duplicate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use directive attributes for differentiating two directives. See below

**In your template**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">  
    <div>Education:  <add add-type = "edu"></add></div>
    <div>Experience: <add add-type = "exp"></add></div>
</body>
```

**and in your js**

```
myApp.directive("add", function($compile){
return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<a href=''>Click to add more sections</a>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        element.bind('click', function()
        {
            if(attrs.addType === 'edu')
                element.prepend($compile("<edu-Info>Add edu</edu-Info>")(scope));
            else if(attrs.addType === 'exp')
                element.prepend($compile("<experience>Add exp</experience>")(scope));
        })
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am able to distinguish between 2 buttons using element.event.id. this field have the id value of the clicked button.

But this method is not working in linux firefox. Do you know why it is not working on linux firefox?

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking about this specific example or a new one. If its this example, I have tested in ubuntu firefox and it works. If its a new example, please post a plunker stating your problem, or post a new question and show some code.

Answer (score 0):

this really sounds like a very bad idea, because what you do is couple your directive to its context (the directive knowing about "button 1" and "button 2")
this clearly isn't a very good approach.
what you could do in the case you described is adding a reference to a variable to the button using the directive.
so for example

```
"<a href='' addedu="correspondingSection">Click to add more sections</a>
```

and then add the value to the given "section" variable (correspondingSection).
this way your directive stays generic and context insensitive